# Dual boot Ubuntu with Win8 with only 1 HDD and 1 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I'm wondering if its possible to install Ubuntu alongside Win8 on a computer with only one hard drive (HDD, 750GB) which has only one partition (there are some additional small recovery partitions). It seems some people claim that one should not resize the partition on which Windows is located. Is that the case and if so won't I be able to dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to resize the partition where windows is installed if you have no other. This is the most usual case and I don't see why those people claim that you shouldn't resize it (and tbh I never saw any claim of this type).

(obs: but let the installer do it for you, do not do it before if you are not sure of how to do it. The installer does that easily and automatically)

Comment: Resizing partitions is not risk-free, which may be the source of the warnings Jonas has heard. To be safe, back up before proceeding. Resizing *usually* completes without causing problems, but it can sometimes fail in a disastrous way. Also, resizing a Windows boot partition in Linux is a little riskier than using Windows for the task, since Linux tools can sometimes render the partition unbootable. *Do not* use Windows tools to create new partitions for Linux, though; that's likely to cause more problems.

Comment: Agreed and good reminder, it is not risk free. Of course you need a backup if you have important data on it but that's always the case. Even turning your computer on can damage the disks so you always need to be prepared. Anyways, resizing the partition is the only way most computers (with a single disk and Windows using it all) have to install a 2nd OS so it is not exactly an experimental task and it is widely used. I think also that the risk of Ubuntu installer resizing the partition alone is a lot smaller than having someone without much experience on this task doing it on his own.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback guys! I've finally managed to install Ubuntu with some dificulty: Ubuntu didn't recognize that Win8 was installed (which seems to be a common problem with computers with UEFI - such as mine). It did however recognize all the partitions. Being afraid that the Ubuntu installer might mess up Windows, I used the Disk Management tool in Windows to shrink the partition. Then I ran the Ubuntu installer again and created 2 partitions from the free space, 1 swap partition equal in size as my amount of RAM and ext4 pratition from the rest of the free space. Then finally I had to change the boot settings so that Grub had 1st priority. And now I have dual boot, happy days!